# Is it possible to create multiple maps using GIS on the same database on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, gis, geoserver

Is it possible to create multiple maps using GIS on the same database on Ubuntu with the help of GeoServer and Postgresql-9.1

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this with a simple "Yes". However providing more help than that will require some more inofrmation about exactly what you mean by multiple maps and GIS. Is this a web app or on a thick client. What operating system ect ect